# Ошибка при создании пакета - ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqldeveloper

Вот мой скрипт для создания пакета:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PP AS
  TYPE REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  FUNCTION getData(id IN VARCHAR2) RETURN REFCURSOR;
END PP;
```

При первом запуске создался пакет. Я добавил процедуру и пытаюсь скомпилировать, выдает ошибку:

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Как мне пересоздать пакет?

Comment: Покажите, как добавили процедуру и компилировали. Пока ничего криминального не видно, все должно работать.

Comment: А как оно выглядит с добавленной процедурой ? Вообще очень странно, пакет просто обязан пересоздаться. И что будет если пакет предварительно удалить DROP PACKAGE

Comment: При команде drop package PP появляется ошибка object PP does not exist

Comment: А вы вообще один с базой работаете? С одной и той же базой все время? Просто других версий нету. Ну еще можете попробовать выполнить `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'PP'`...

Comment: У вас комманда содержит begin-end блок и нет завершения команды "/". Выполняются следуюшая(ие) команда(ы) в промокашке и все эти "странности" и ошибки к текущему пакету не относятся.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не хватает завершающего символа после объявления пакета. Надо так:

```
...
END PP;
/
```

Отличия и общее для завершающих символов "/" и ";" в *SQl Developer* следующее:

- Оба символа не входят в стандарт SQL и никак в SQL запросе не интепритируются.
- ";" является составной частью языка PL/SQL, он завершает законченое выражение.
- Оба не посылаются на сервер, а служат только как служебные символы - "здесь конец".

В одной вкладке редактора (*SQL Worksheet*) могут находится многочисленные запросы и анонимные блоки. Поэтому, для выполнения одного запроса или блока (по умолчанию с CTRL-ENTER), необходимо:

- SQL запросы не содержащих PL/SQL блока, в частности - все DML, некоторые DDL, DCL - необходимо завершить его либо с ";", либо с "/" на новой строке.
- Анонимные блоки и SQL запросы содержащие PL/SQL блок (`create ... package/function/trigger/...` ) или потенциально могущие его содержать  (`create ... type`), необходимо завершить его с "/", т.к. ";" завершает последний END в блоке.

Если *SQl Developer* не находит завершающих символов, он ищет их дальше по тексту, и когда их найдёт (если не найдёт, то до конца текста), посылает несколько запросов поочереди, что приводит к неопределённому результату.   Обычно, к ошибке выполнения, которая не совсем понятна.

Например:

```
create type idType as object (id number);
show errors
/
```

> Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SHOW"

---

На заметку: Если запрос или блок выделить визуально, тогда *SQl Developer* выполнит только выделенное, даже если завершающие символы отсутствуют.